# Why does ON LIKE ignore some occurences (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, string, join, sql-like

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT dodavatel, odberatel, jmeno
FROM objednavky
LEFT JOIN odberatel
ON objednavky.odberatel LIKE CONCAT('%', odberatel.jmeno, '%')
ORDER BY odberatel
LIMIT 0, 7000;
```

Despite the condition, the result looks this way and I can not figure out any reason, why the ON LIKE condition does not catch all the occurences.

[image: SQL query result example]

Do you see any possible solution?

Comment: Deeply inspect the values and I'm willing to bet the strings are not identical.  It appears likely that there are whitespace characters or control code characters hidden in there.

Comment: try this one: **ON objednavky.odberatel LIKE '%'+ odberatel.jmeno +'%'**

Comment: @AliSheikpour - MySQL doesn't naturally use the + operator for concatenation.  And even if it did why would the results be different?

Comment: also try **ON instr(objednavky.odberatel , odberatel.jmeno)>0** also consider comparing upper case of values if uppercase and lowercase happens

Comment: It looks like there is empty `jmeno` field value in one or more records in `odberatel` table. `LIKE '%%'` will result in `true` on any value.